# norm of the vector is greater than the absolute value of the eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A \in \mathbb R^{m×m}$ , and suppose that $3+4i$ is an eigenvalue
>   of A. 
>  a) Show that $\|Au\|^2_2 + \|Av\|^2_2 = 25(\|u\|^2_2 +\|v\|^2_2)$ . 
>   b) Prove that $\|Au\|_2 \geq 5$.

**My attempt:**
a) $3+4i$ is an eigenvalue $\implies A(u+iv) = (3+4i)(u+iv)$ or $Au = 3u-4v$ and $Av = 4u+3v$. So $\|Au\|^2_2 + \|Av\|^2_2 = (3u-4v)^T(3u-4v) + (4u+3v)^T(4u+3v) = 9u^Tu -12u^Tv-12v^Tu+16v^Tv+16u^T+12u^Tv+12v^Tu+9v^Tv=25(u^Tu+v^Tv)=25(\|u\|^2_2
 +\|v\|^2_2)$.
Is this correct and how to approach the second part?

Comment: What $>+$ means ? Also the second result is false. In order to be true you need extra assumption such that : $3+4i$ is the smallest eigenvalue value of $A$ for the absolute norm

Answer (score 1):

I guess that by $u+iv$ you mean an eigenvector relative to the given eigenvalue, decomposed into real and imaginary parts.

Then $Au+iAv=A(u+iv)=(3+4i)(u+iv)=(3u-4v)+i(4u+3v)$ implies
$$
Au=3u-4v,\qquad Av=4u+3v
$$
Your computation is correct:
\begin{align}
\|Au\|_2^2&=(3u-4v)^T(3u-4v)=9u^Tu-12v^Tu-12u^Tv+16v^Tv \\
\|Av\|_2^2&=(4u+3v)^T(4u+3v)=16u^Tu+12v^Tu+12u^Tv+9v^Tv
\end{align}
and summing up
$$
\|Au\|_2^2+\|Av\|_2^2=25(\|u\|_2^2+\|v\|_2^2)
$$

The second part is false unless you have some further assumptions on $u$. Indeed, if $a$ is any positive real number, then $a(u+iv)$ is again an eigenvector relative to $3+4i$, but
$$
\|A(au)\|_2=a\|Au\|_2
$$
For $a\to0$, also $a\|Au\|_2\to0$, so it will become less than $5$ for a suitable choice of $a$.

Comment: Then how the norm of $A$ is related to the eigenvalues? For real matrices I know how to prove $\|A\| \geq $ eigenvalue of $A$, its a little confusing with real and imaginary parts of complex matrices